# How to create "named mutual exclusive access" in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, locking, mutex

I have a class that produce stuff based on a string:

`string Produce(string key);`

The result is cached so it is only produced one. Now I would like to lock down the production method. I only want the method to lock on the key... if another key comes in, it should not lock.

I've switched from a `lock` to a named `Mutex`, but I read that this method is slow as the `Mutex` is OS wide. How would I go about to create somesort of named lock?

<sub>I'm using .Net 3.5</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a simple string to object lock dictionary work?

```
object _superLock = new object();
Dictionary<string, object> _locks = new Dictionary<string, object>();

string Produce(string key) {
    lock(GetLock(key)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

object GetLock(string key) {
    lock(_superLock) {
        if (!_locks.ContainsKey(key)) {
            _locks[key] = new object();
        }
    }
    return _locks[key];
}
```

Update: Oh right, ConcurrentDictionary exists. That might look something like

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
object GetLock(string key) {
    return _locks.GetOrAdd(key, k => new object());
}
```

Comment: Wow... sounds nice... I'll try turning it into a class. I'm wondering if .Net doesn't have something like this. It "feels" quite elementary.

Comment: Use ConcurrentDictionary<,> instead of a simple one with manual locking.

Comment: @chase, I'm still on 3.5 :(

Comment: Your ConcurrentDictionary has a bug in that the lambda to GetOrAdd can be called concurrently. It is not exclusive.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a well-defined behavior. The factory may be called multiple times for a given key, but only one of the resulting values will be persisted (and returned from `GetOrAdd`).

Comment: He wants the cache value to be produced only once. This is important to avoid cache stampeding issues.

Comment: That `GetLock()` returns the object to lock on, not the value to cache.

Comment: Ah indeed. Now the problem is that he'll be seeing contention when heavy ready occur for the same key.

Comment: I'm assuming that his value caching mechanism already has that covered, that Produce is only called if the cache doesn't already have a value.

Answer (score 1):

A `ConcurrentDictionary` makes this very easy:

```
public class Foo
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> locks =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    public string Produce(string key)
    {
        lock (locks.GetOrAdd(key, new object()))
        {
            //TODO do whatever
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty much a canonical solution to this:

```
var cacheItems = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>>();
...
TValue Get(Func<TValue> factory) {
 return cacheItems.GetOrAdd(_ => new Lazy<TValue>(factory)).Value;
}
```

This has the following important properties:

1. It is safe.
2. The value for a given key is only ever produced once (important to prevent cache stampeding and to save resources).
3. No contention when reading.

Multiple `Lazy`'s might be produced but only one will ever be forced to evaluate.